# Missing __stack_chk_fail Symbol Using GCC

Tags: c, gcc, stack, buffer-overflow

Based on what I've seen with hardening audit tools the way to detect stack cookies/canaries is to dump symbols with readelf -s and look for the __stack_chk_fail symbol.

I build my code with -fstack-protector-strong and as expected canaries are generally detected. The problem is some of the binaries I build don't have the __stack_chk_fail even though the -fstack-protector-strong option is used.

Are there situations/conditions where binaries may not include the __stack_chk_fail symbol even though stack protection is enabled?

Comment: Surely a symbol `__stack_chk_fail` would be specific to a particular C or instrumentation implementation, so your question can't be answered in the full generality in which you've posed it.

Comment: Thanks John, I modified the title to show that I'm using GCC

Comment: I would suppose that a compiler that knows how to inject stack-checking instrumentation must be able to determine where stack checking is needed -- and where it is not needed.  If it happens that the compiler determines that no instrumentation is needed around any function in a given program, then I wouldn't expect it to link `__stack_chk_fail()`.  We can't speak to whether that might be the case for a particular program without seeing the program.